# mongodb getting user info for every document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to display a forum/category. I need to get the latest posts. The problem is that I also need data on the user for each post as well as the latest reply.

```
db.post.find({
  "inForum": forumID,
},
{
  'sort': [['date', -1]]
},
function(err, cursor) {
  cursor.count(function(err, count) {
    cursor.skip(skip).limit(20).toArray(function(err, posts) {
      var complete = _.after(nodes.length, function () {
        res.send(posts)
      });

      // for every post get its author info and the latest post info
      posts.forEach(function (post) {
        var users = _.pluck(posts, 'user');
        user.load(users, function (profiles) {
          _.each(posts,
          function(post, k) {
            if (profiles[post.user]) post.fieldAvatar = profiles[post.user].fieldAvatar;
          });

          if (post.latestReply) {
            post.load(post.latestReply.id, function (latestReply) {
              if (latestReply) post.latestReply = latestReply
              complete()
            })
          }
          else {
            complete()
          }
        })
      })
    });
  })
})
```

This is what I'm doing and it seems really slow / really inelegant to me. Am I doing this correctly and is there any advice for speeding this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you should do here is to embed some information for the author of the posts (username & email or avatar) into those posts so that you don't make multiple queries to the database, one should suffice (sure you have some duplicate data, but the performance is optimal).

If you don't want to / can't do that you can also modify your second query to find all authors in [array_of_ids_of_the_posts]. That would reduce your [number_of_posts] queries into only one.

Comment: Yeah I actually have this optimization elsewhere in my code but I forgot to include it in the example. user.load uses `"$in": users` rather than doing a loop

Comment: If you do either one (preferably the first) of the things mentioned you'll be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, interestingly i did it with user but used a loop for latest posts instead passing an array. Silly me, thanks

Comment: No problem, try to put the username and email/avatar in the posts collection also, that would be a great thing to do for performance. You only need the whole user info on the user page, so putting some user info into the posts collection would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some caching. For example you could save the users in an dictionary during the loop so you only have to fetch it on the first occurrence from mongodb.

Maybe you could create some kind of thread model where you save basic information about the containing posts, so you only have to go through the threads.

You could save the result of the function and delete it when a new post is added .. so won't go through all posts on every call.

You should not use a document storage like a sql database. Maybe it is better to generate the forum page directly when a post is created/edited and save the whole data in a document, so you only have to make one read call to mongo to show it.